# Questions about Merton's derivation of the security market line

Tags: capm, mean-variance

In Merton's "An Analytic Derivation of the Efficient Frontier" ([PDF](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/%7Enchristo/statistics_c183_c283/analytic_derivation_frontier.pdf)), he derives the security market line for the CAPM using the definition of the tangency portfolio. He writes:

[image]

Here, $m$ is the number of assets in the portfolio, $M$ denotes the market portfolio, and $x$ are the portfolio weights, so $x^M$ denote the market portfolio weights. I don't understand this for a couple reasons:

1. I know that $\sigma_M = \sqrt{(w^M)^{\top} \Sigma w^M}$. But I don't understand why $\sigma_{kM}$, which I interpret to be the cross covariance between the $k$-th asset and the market portfolio ($\sigma_k \sigma_M$) is a sum of weighted cross-covariances.
2. I don't understand what the sum is over. Is it over $i$ or $j$? I would guess $i$ because of $x_i^M$ but then what is $j$?
3. Finally, he says "from $(44)$ but this is equation $42$. I don't think he's referencing    a future equation. This must mean equation $41$?

Comment: Some unemployed genius should use his spare time to re-type this wonderful article with all the typos corrected.

Comment: In the first line it is probably $\sigma_{ik}$ and not $\sigma_{ij}$ and the summation index is i (i is the only free index; k is bound to the k on the LHS). This line is computing $\Sigma x$, which is an intermediate step in the calculation of $x^T \Sigma x$ and is also the derivative of $\frac{1}{2}x^T \Sigma x$ with respect to $x$. Yes, he is probably referring to equation (41).